# Azure Kubernetes Service: How to cut the costing of my virtual machines without changing architecture of my node pools?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have azure Kubernetes cluster with the following node pools:

1. **Database pool** with **1** node count and **Standard_B4ms** node vm size.
2. **Content pool** with **1** node count and **Standard_B4ms** node vm size.
3. **Application pool** with **1** node count and **Standard_B2ms** node vm size.
4. **Content spot pool** with **1** node count and **Standard_D2a_v4** node vm size.
5. **Application spot pool** with **1** node count and **Standard_D2a_v4** node vm size.

The **Content spot pool** and **Application spot pool** are the 2 spot node pools. Rest of the others are regular node pools. I'm using spot node pools to cut the costing of my azure instances as  much as possible.

I have deployed 2 nginx pods on **Content spot pool** and **Application spot pool** respectively. I set it up in such way that, If the spot node pools are get evicted then the 1 pod of nginx is shift to **Content pool** and other nginx pod is shift to **Application pool** with the proper use of *tolerations* and *affinity*.

But to achieve above mentioned scenario, I have to setup regular node pools' node count is to **1**. If I set the node count of regular node to 0, then it is unable to move pods.

Is there any solution, where **"I don't have to insert, delete, update my node pool architecture but also I'm able to cut the azure costing for VMs?"**

Thanks.

AKS version used - 1.18.14

Comment: Set up cluster autoscaling on the regular nodepools to min 0 & max 1. It'll autoscale the nodepool to bring up a new node when spot is evicted (but you'll see downtime as the pod doesn't have anywhere to run until new node is up).

Comment: @mmking Yes. It is working..!

Comment: Also If you again create spot node pool then automatically pods are shifts to the spot node pool and regular node pools are scale down to 0

Comment: That's good to know for another day! :)